# Do you need to free a string from 'strcpy' if you copy a string generated from malloc?

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

Say I have some code snippet

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10)
// some code to add content to the string in some way
```

To create a string of 10 chars. If I then copy `str` with `strcpy` from the standard string library into a new variable like so

```
char *copy;
strcpy(copy, str);
```

I'm aware I then need to free `str` using `free(str)`, but is that enough? Or does `strcpy` also dynamically allocate memory for `copy` if used on a string created from malloc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or does strcpy also dynamically allocate memory for copy

No, `strcpy` knows nothing about memory, so your code copies a string into an uninitialized pointer pointing at la-la land.

If you want allocation + copy in the same call, there is non-standard `strdup` for that (which looks like it will be added to the C standard in the next version of the language).

Alternatively just do `char *copy = malloc(strlen(str)+1);` and then `strcpy`. Keep in mind to always leave room for the null terminator.

Comment: Afaik strcpy also copies the null terminator. Would that mean if I was 100% certain that the string I copy has a null terminator I wouldn't need the +1 in your malloc call?

Comment: @SomeCoderOnTheWeb `strcpy` copies the terminator but you have to make sure there's room. If the string is 10 characters long then you obviously need to allocate 11, or strcpy will access the data out of bounds when it writes the terminator.

Comment: @SomeCoderOnTheWeb no, as `strlen` does not count the null terminator. `strlen("abc" ) == 3`, while the underlying char array is of size 4, `{'a','b','c', '\0'}` and that what needs to be copied (and is copied by `strcpy`).

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` does not allocate, thus your second snippet is invalid unless `copy` is initialized with some buffer (regardless of it being stack- or heap allocated) or is is a large enough array.

Side note: if you don't know the exact length of the source string, you need to make sure the target buffer size is not exceed (e.g. by using `strncpy` or providing a large enough target buffer).

I guess [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) should answer your question in detail.

Comment: `strncpy` is a poor choice as it may leave you without the null terminator.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it may, but with known size it is not that much of a problem IMHO. Granted, I'd probably also go with sth else but it really depends on the context.

Comment: @Jabberwocky What would you recommend then?

Comment: @SomeCoderOnTheWeb use `strcpy` and make sure the destination buffer is long enough.

Comment: @SomeCoderOnTheWeb as for other options (it's not exhaustive): checking the size of source string and providing big enough buffer, using non-standard `strdup` and last but not least, one can copy the truncated source and add null-terminator manually if the buffer of proper size cannot be provided. Really depends on one's needs. But simply providing and proper buffer seems a sane default for a general case.

Comment: Telling people to use `strncpy` is always bad and incorrect advise. Please study [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Answer (score 0):

For starters the pointer copy is not initialized

```
char *copy;
```

So this call of strcoy

```
strcpy(copy, str);
```

results in undefined behavior.

The pointer `copy` must point to a character array where the string pointed to by the pointer `str` will be copied.

You need to free what was allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc.

So if the target array pointed to by the pointer copy was dynamically allocated like for example

```
char *copy = malloc( 10 * sizeof( char ) );
```

then of course you will need to free the allocated memory when it is not required any more.

This has nothing common with the function `strcpy` that just copies a string from one character array to another character array.